# Where are Minecraft worlds located on mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Minecraft world called "hotel", but when i open up my saves folder, the world isn't in it. I am on a mac. Where can I find it?

Comment: Could you specify what you do when you "open up my minecraft saves folder"? From within the game, via a file explorer, or?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [World is playable but not located in saves folder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291170/world-is-playable-but-not-located-in-saves-folder)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, a world has a different world name than that of its in-game name.

You can see the folder name of any world by looking at the name next to the date. As you can see in this picture, the title of the world is different to its folder name, which can be found next to the red arrow.

[image: picture showing this difference]

Simply look in the 'saves' folder for the folder name of your world.

Comment: Australian English?

Comment: @CreeperzEdge Yep :P As an Aussie, I love it.

Comment: yay im not alone in this world as an aussie